# Codeigniter updating database record list

Tags: database, codeigniter, records

Ok i have in view file record form db and i am trying to pass it to controler, then to method where i try to do update

```
$this->db->select('info');
$query = $this->db->get('pages');
 foreach ($query->result() as $q): ?>
<a href="update/updating/<?php echo $q->info?>"><?php echo $q->info . br()?></a>
```

in my controler i have code

```
public function updating($var){
        $data['info']= $var;
        $this->load->view("view_update",$data);
```

}
which load view file where i want to insert new value with form

```
echo br() . $this->session->flashdata('item');
echo '<h4>Azuriranje Podataka </h4>';
echo "Old data is:" .$info;


echo form_open('update/updating');

$data = array('name'=>'field');
echo form_input().br().br();
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Posalji');
echo form_close()
```

my question what should i do with $info i dont wanna submit it via form and input field how to grab it again in controler???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You can't do it.

What you **can** do is store the item in a cookie (cookies are sent with POST requests), OR just use a form.

ALOT of places use hidden input fields to send information, if you're afraid the data will be tampered with you can use a variaty of hashing techniques to make sure the data is safe, I'll not go into depth here as it's out of the scope of your question but i'll explain further if needed by a comment.

The problem you're facing is equivalent to sending arguments from **A** website(ANY WEBSITE), to your controller. Just because the view is generated from your controller, does not mean the controller that catchs the POST request knows where it came from, or what it contains.(that's why we have cookies or POST data)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong.

Firstly, you are executing SQL select statement inside your view file, which is not standard practice and it is not in the spirit of the MVC pattern. So first thing you have to do is actually change the logic you are thinking when using the CodeIgniter. This way, your code will be much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Inside your model, you should write method which retrieves your data.

```
public function getPages(){
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    return $query
}
```

Inside your controller you can call this model method by:

```
$this->load->model("your_model");
$data["pages"]=$this->your_model->getPages();
$this->load->view("yourviewfile.php",$data);//In this line, you are passing data to the view file
```

Inside your view file you can go through the data

```
foreach ($pages as $q)://You've passed $pages from the controller, so $pages variable is now accessible ?>
<a href="update/updating/<?php echo $q->info?>"><?php echo $q->info . br()?></a>
```

Now, if you want to send some data back from the view file to the controller, you should use GET or POST form submission or AJAX call.

Example of the POST method:

```
<form action=<?php echo base_url()."controllerName/actionName" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="ime" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```